# Conversion of bigint to date only in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have column with BigInt datatype and I am trying to convert as only "Date".

By using the query below, I am getting a DateTime but I am looking only for Date.

```
Select DATEADD(SECOND, cast(SR.EXECUTED_ON as bigint) / 1000, '19700101') as ExecutedOn from table1
```

**Result:** `"2019-02-19 06:32:06.000"`

But I was expecting `"2019-02-19"`.

Can someone please help on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CAST` to `DATE`  like following.

```
SELECT Cast(Dateadd(second, Cast(sr.executed_on AS BIGINT) / 1000, '19700101') 
            AS DATE) 
       AS ExecutedOn 
FROM   table1
```